# Unit test does not work as expected - instead of 404, it returns 200 as status code

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-mvc, mockito

I am writing the unit tests for an application which converts an amount of money with a particular currency to EUR. I have in a database some accounts which have: iban, currency and balance.

In order to get all the currencies and their value in EUR, an API call is made in order to get the exchange rate. The method of converting receives the iban of the account and returns the amount of money from the account in EUR.
The app works fine, but I have some issues with the unit tests.

I am trying to write a unit test for the case when the account cannot be found - so when the method from `AccountController` class - `getAccountByIban` returns 404. I wrote the test and added as IBAN a random String - but instead of 404, I get 200 as response code and the test fails. If I call the method `getAccountByIban` with that random IBAN from the test, I get the right response code - 404.

Here is my code:

AccountController:

```
@RestController
public class AccountController {

    @Autowired
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder;

    @Autowired
    AccountService accountService;

    @ApiOperation(value = "Get account with given iban ", response = AccountEntity.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/account/{iban}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public AccountDTO getAccountByIban(@PathVariable("iban") String iban ) throws AccountNotFoundException {

        return Optional
                .ofNullable(accountService.getAccountByIban(iban))
                .orElseThrow(() -> new AccountNotFoundException("Requested account was not found! [ iban = " + iban + "]"));
    }

    @ApiOperation(value = "Get account with amount converted ", response = AccountEntity.class)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/account/exchange/{iban}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
    public AccountDTO getAmountConvertedByIban(@PathVariable("iban") String iban) {

        AccountDTO accountDTO = accountService.getAccountByIban(iban);
        Double currentBalance = accountDTO.getBalance();
        String currentCurrency = accountDTO.getCurrency();
        Double actualBalance = accountService.getCurrencyValue(currentCurrency) * currentBalance;
        accountDTO.setBalance(actualBalance);
        return accountDTO;
    }
}
```

AccountService:

```
public class AccountService {

    @Autowired
    AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired
    RequestBuilder requestBuilder;

    @Autowired
    CurrencyDTO currencyDTO;

    @Cacheable("exchangeRates")
    public Double getCurrencyValue(String currency) {

        return currencyDTO.getCurrencyValue(currency);

    }

    public AccountDTO getAccountByIban(String iban){

        AccountDTO accountDTO = null;
        AccountEntity accountEntity = accountRepository.findByIban(iban);

        if (accountEntity != null ) {
            accountDTO = accountEntity.toDTO();
        }

        return accountDTO;
    }
}
```

Class with UNIT test:

```
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class AccountServiceTest {


    @MockBean
    AccountController accountController;

    @Spy
    @InjectMocks
    AccountService accountService;

    @Mock
    AccountRepository accountRepository;

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Before
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        AccountEntity accountEntity = new AccountEntity();
        accountEntity.setIban("RO06PORL4513558777471397");
        accountEntity.setBalance(10000D);
        accountEntity.setCurrency("RON");

        Mockito.when(accountRepository.save(accountEntity)).thenReturn(accountEntity);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAccountNotFound() throws Exception {

        mockMvc.perform(get("/account/RO2E2"))
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
        //Assert.assertTrue(accountService.getAccountByIban("RO06PORL4513558777471397") == null);
```

AccountDTO:

```
public class AccountDTO {

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Account ID",name="id",required=true,value="id")
    private int id;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Account IBAN",name="iban",required=true,value="iban")
    private String iban;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Account Currency",name="currency",required=true,value="currency")
    private String currency;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Account Balance",name="balance",required=true,value="balance")
    private Double balance;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Last Update",name="lastUpdate",required=true,value="lastUpdate")
    private Date lastUpdate;
```

Can anyone help me correct my test class ? I cannot see what I am doing wrong

Comment: Add breakpoint here AccountEntity accountEntity = accountRepository.findByIban(iban);
is accountEntitiy null or something else?

Comment: I have experience with C#'s `Moq`, not Java's `Mockito`, but what does the automatic mock setup return when you do not specify a behaviour? Do you need to manually tell it to return 404 by default, and only return 200 for ibans that you specify in the setup?

Comment: please post the code for the class AccountNotFoundException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inverting the concept of Controller and Service, and mocking too much, confusing the testing framework.

When you want to test the outcome of a Controller, you should use MockMvc against *the real Controller* (in a ControllerTest class, not in a ServiceTest class), then mocking *the Service* used by the Controller to have it return what you want to the Controller.

Something like:

```java
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
// @SpringBootTest 
// Not needed the whole context here, just use the faster way:
@WebMvcTest(AccountControllerTest.class)
public class AccountControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    AccountService accountService;    

    @Test
    public void testAccountFound() throws Exception {
        when(accountService.getAccountByIban("123"))
          .thenReturn(new AccountDTO(...));

        mockMvc.perform(get("/account/123"))
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    public void testAccountNotFound() throws Exception {
        when(accountService.getAccountByIban("123"))
          .thenReturn(null);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/account/123"))
                .andExpect(status().isNotFound());
    }

}
```

Then, when you need to test the Service in a ServiceTest class, you won't use MockMvc, because you want to test the communication between Service and Repository, not between Controller and Service. Always follow the flow. 
There, you will mock the repository, and test that Service outputs the proper results with the different (mocked) repository results.

---

That said, when the return type of a method is optional, you should use Optional as return type, not null and then using Optional externally, hence:

```java
public Optional<AccountDTO> getAccountByIban(String iban){

    AccountEntity accountEntity = accountRepository.findByIban(iban);

    if (accountEntity != null ) {
        return Optional.of(accountEntity.toDTO());
    }

    return Optional.empty();
}
```

And

```java
@ApiOperation(value = "Get account with given iban ", response = AccountEntity.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/account/{iban}", method = RequestMethod.GET )
public AccountDTO getAccountByIban(@PathVariable("iban") String iban ) throws AccountNotFoundException {

    return accountService.getAccountByIban(iban)
             .orElseThrow(() -> new AccountNotFoundException("Requested account was not found! [ iban = " + iban + "]"));
}
```

And

```java
when(accountService.getAccountByIban("123"))
  .thenReturn(Optional.of(new AccountDTO(...)));

when(accountService.getAccountByIban("123"))
  .thenReturn(Optional.empty());
```

Also make sure that AccountNotFoundException is annotated with

```java
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the explanations, it worked !!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting strange results, because you are trying to test your service, using `mockMvc` which is helpful for unit testing controllers or doing some integration tests. It seems that Mocking your controller bean results in returning always 200 status.

What I see is you are mixing unit test with integration test, because you are using `@SpringBootTest` along with repository mocking.

I recommend to convert your test to unit and not throw an exception in your controller. Your `accountService` may return `Optional<AccountDto>` and your controller then may return `ResponseEntity<AccountDto>`. Then code in your controller method may look like:

```
    return dto.map(ResponseEntity::ok)
            .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
```

and you're in your test setup you may mock your service with empty optional.

Moreover, if you want to use integration tests, then you can use an embedded H2 database for that, and insert some data to your database before the test.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Why is he/she getting 200?

Comment: I made the changes, but I still get 200 :(

Comment: @Maria1995 it happens because you are mocking the controller. Try to create a unit test for the controller and mock service then use mockmvc to check the endpoint. If you want to test your service, then mock only repositories and test service methods directly